# How to iterate json collection using ng repeat angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

My service gives below json result

```
 {"categories":[{"category_id":"20","name":"Desktops"},  {"category_id":"18","name":"Laptops &amp},{"category_id":"25","name":"Components"},
{"category_id":"57","name":"Tablets"},
{"category_id":"17","name":"Software"},
{"category_id":"24","name":"Phones} ]}
```

this is my html code:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="menu in menuitems">
    <td>
        {{menu.name}}
    </td>
```

in controller I fill `$scope.menuitems` with the json result

I am not able to render the list of names in html. If I write  `{{menu[0].name}}` I do get one record.What am i doing wrong that I am unable to iterate over the json collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-repeat` directive works over an array.

So, in your case `menuitems` is the variable where you store the response json object.

Your json's structure shows that it contains an array `categories` of objects.

Therefore, for ng-repeat to work, you need to pass in `menuitems.categories` to it.

Expression:

```
<tr ng-repeat="menu in menuitems.categories">
<td>
    {{menu.name}}
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is inside an object. So, you must use,

```
 <tr ng-repeat="menu in menuitems.categories">
<td>
    {{menu.name}}
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate all objects and track them
I dont know about your controller but try add this line of code

```
ng-repeat="menu in menuitems track by $index
```